# Access <html> node

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add a class to the `<html>` element and run the code for it in the `<head>` element. What's the best way to do that?

`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = 'class';`

or

`document.documentElement.className = 'class';`

Comment: Take great care when doing this, especially on the anti-browser. Do test on all supported browsers, because some consider the `html` element special in some way.

Comment: Why would you need to add a class to `<html>` instead of the `<body>` ?

Comment: @Teneff, to have less elements on the page.

Comment: `document.body.parentNode`

Answer (score 4):

Neither way is really 'better', but `documentElement` is a tiny bit faster, because it doesn't have to run the matching function, so go with it.

Comment: `document.body.parentNode`

Answer (score 3):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) seems to use document.documentElement (by looking at the source).

I guess that's a good reference :)

Comment: Typekit uses document.getElementsByTagName, also a good reference ; )